Open Azure Cloud Shell to bash or powershell
You can use specific urls like https://shell.azure.com/ or https://portal.azure.com/#cloudshell/ to open the azure portal with the azure cloud shell in focus. How can I select the specific flavor of shell that opens? I specifically want to make sure the user is opening bash, but I'm sure there's a way to specify powershell also.
-- edit
things I've tried so far that don't seem to work
https://shell.azure.com/?shell=bash, https://shell.azure.com/?shell=powershell
https://shell.azure.com/?feature.bash=true
https://shell.azure.com/bash, https://shell.azure.com/powershell
https://portal.azure.com/#cloudshell/bash, https://portal.azure.com/#cloudshell/powershell


Can you share more if tried any approach so far! @JJS

@Jahnavi I've modified the question with things I've tried that did not work.

AFAIK,there is no such option to open the shells based on url's .By default last selected shell option will be opened.

By default, Cloud shell opens the Powershell option.


If you click on the new session, it opens the flavor which is currently set on the main page.

Currently my current session has PowerShell, when I open a new session with the https://ms.portal.azure.com/#cloudshell/ URL it opens the PowerShell windows itself.




When I open new session with Bash on main page, new session opens a Bash window.



The above URL opens the PowerShell/Bash based on the main page selection.

AFAIK, there is no such option to open the Cloud shell flavor using the URL.

Cloud shell remembers the last selected flavor and opens the same for the next time.

